# Google Cloud Storage: Getting object from hiarchial / sub-folder structure

Tags: c#, api, google-cloud-platform, cloud, storage

I have created hierarchical structure for managing file in bucket. Planning to create folder for each month i.e. dec-2017. There will be more than 10k pdf files in each folder.

Written C# code for getting objects from bucket. This code is working fine for accessing files that are on root of bucket. I am having issues with accessing files in folder i.e. my-bucket/dec-2017/test.pdf is not accessed using code.

[Refer my bucket structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoP6G.png)

I am using following code, Can anyone don this before?

```
if (_storageService == null)
{
    _storageService = CreateStorageClient();
}
ObjectsResource.GetRequest downloadRequest = null;
//string objectName = "dec-2017%2Ftest.pdf";
string objectName = "dec-2017/test.pdf";

downloadRequest = new ObjectsResource.GetRequest(_storageService, bucketName, objectName);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
downloadRequest.Download(stream);
bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend using our Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 package, which wraps the Google.Apis.Storage.v1 library you're currently using. I'd *expect* the code you've given to work, although I've never used that `Download` method - the Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 library uses the media download request approach instead.

Comment: Additionally, it would help if you'd say what happens when you try downloading that file - do you get an error? If so, what? If not, what *do* you get?

Comment: I've just tried this, and it works fine for me. If you want to keep using StorageService, I'd encourage you to use `_storageService.Objects.Get(bucketName, objectName)` rather than calling the constructor directly - but it's even simpler to just use `StorageClient` in the wrapper API.

Comment: My requirement is to download multiple files in memory as per users request and combine/merge  those files in memory and download in user's browser. 

With above code no error is thrown but file is not getting downloaded. 

I have used Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 and file are downloading correcly but Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 need .NET Framework 4.5. All our servers are working on .NET 4.0.

Comment: Hi Jon,

Thanks for your reply !!!

Is there any way that we can run Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 in .NET Framework 3.5?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Have you tried using your existing code (that worked for me) from a .NET 4.5 app? I wonder whether that difference is relevant.

Comment: Note that the `Download` method doesn't provide any way of indicating errors (an unfortunate API decision which we can't change) - whereas if you use the MediaDownloader approach, you can see the final progress. I've just remembered that the pre-.NET-4.5 versions of Google.Storage.Apis.v1 also use a very old version of the support libraries (Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Core) so it's possible there's a bug there. How feasible would it be to update your servers to use a more recent version of .NET? Aside from anything else, I would be concerned about security vulnerabilities in such old versions

Answer (score 0):

Please check below sample code -

```
        using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
        using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;

        string file = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test.csv");
        File.WriteAllText(file, "test");

        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        BucketConnector bucketConnector = new BucketConnector();
        credential = bucketConnector.ConnectStream();
        var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

        string folderPath = ConfigurationParameters.FOLDER_NAME_IN_BUCKET;
        using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(localPath))
        {
            objectName = folderPath + Path.GetFileName(localPath);
            storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, file);           
        }
```

Comment: Here folderPath  you can configure or generate dynamically

Comment: Can you please add some context to explain how your code answers the question?